# why spring batch creates a new instance when i try to restart the day after a failed job?

Tags: spring-batch

[image datas from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I59ys.png)

I have a failed execution instance in my repository on date 2016-03-14.

If i try to restart the job's instance on the date of 2016-03-15, a new instance and a new execution with the previous job's parameters (2016-03-14) are creating.

But the job is restarting a complete step instead of doing a recover process(starting at the last line before the fail event).

Why i have a new instance?

If i restart on the same day (failed job and the restarted job) i have no problem (one instance sharing between job's execution).

EDIT:
I start my job with this code:

`@Bean
    public Job myJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step stepInjectCsvWsIntoCsv) {
            return jobs.get("myJob")
                   .listener(new JobListener())
                   .incrementer(new RunIdDateIncrementor())
                   .flow(stepInjectCsvWsIntoCsv)
                   .end().build();
    }`

RunIdDateIncrementor is my own class. It's here that i create parameters (run.id and run.date)

I use a FlatItemReader and a CompositeWriter which manage two MultiResourceItemWriter and implements ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream

And the step configuration :

```
@Bean(name = "stepInjectCsvWsIntoCsv")
public Step stepInjectCsvWsIntoCsv(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<GetDataInCsv> csvReader,
        CompositeTwoCsvFileItemWriter getDataWriter,
        ItemProcessor<GetDataInCsv, List<GetDataOutCsv>> getDataProcessor
        ) {
    /* it handles bunches of 10 units => limité à 10 stations*/
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepInjectCsvWsIntoCsv").listener(new StepListener())
            .<GetDataInCsv, List<GetDataOutCsv>> chunk(1)
            .reader(csvReader).processor(getDataProcessor).writer(getDataWriter)
            .faultTolerant().skipLimit(1000).skip(GetDataFault.class)
            .listener(new CustomChunkListener())
            .listener(new CustomItemReaderListener())
            .listener(new GetDataItemProcessListener())
            .listener(new CustomItemWriterListener())
            .build();
}
```

I have a new instance then an empty execution context and so the restart isn't detected.

I use SPRING BOOT too.
The Launch

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BatchWsVersCsv implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchWsVersCsv.class);

        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(new Object[] { BatchWsVersCsv.class });

        Map<String, Object> defaultProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        //set some default properties
        //...

        springApplication.setDefaultProperties(defaultProperties);

        springApplication.run(args);

    }

    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("running...");

    }

}
```

Comment: Can we see the code you're using to launch the job (as well as the job's configuration)?

Comment: I really appreciate your help Michael, thanks. Tell me if you need more precision.

Comment: So here is my question.  What are the job parameters being stored in the job repository with each job instance?  Are they different and if so, what's the difference?  Job parameters are what indicates if a new JobInstance should be created or not.  So if somewhere in the above code you're passing in a new or different parameter on the restart, you'll get a new JobInstance.

Comment: i added an image which show bdd datas. I have same parameters but 2 instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's my bad. For testing an error event on day before, i do a request in data base for updating all date.
So the serialized key in batch_instance isn't match anymore.
If i change the system date for generating error on day before, all works prefectly if i run a restart the day after.